# Get user's temp directory in makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, tmp

I'm trying to learn the location of the temp directory a user is configured to use. The [GNU Make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Directory-Variables.html) mentions `TMPDIR` in the *Directory Variables* section:

> [runstatedir] directory should not be cleaned except perhaps at reboot, while the general /tmp (TMPDIR) may be cleaned arbitrarily.

But I can't find `TMPDIR` documented in [Directory Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Directory-Variables.html), [Implicit Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html) or [Automatic Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html).

Somewhat surprisingly (to me), searching is not producing useful hits. I found a couple of questions on Stack Overflow about creating a unique temp directory based on a PID ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3860137/608639) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/589252/608639)), but nothing for a temp directory we are supposed to use at build time for scratch work.

Does GNU Make provide a variable for the temporary directory to use during a build? If so, what is it?

If not, then what should we do to learn the temporary directory configured for a user? In this case, I'm wondering what the practice is.

Answer (score 2):

TMPDIR is not a standard Make or shell variable.
It is what tempnam(3) checks when creating a tempfile path (defaulting to "/tmp").

gmake does use tempnam hence $TMPDIR. But you (the invoker of gmake) are the one who sets it.

Comment: GNU make provides no such variable.
It has no way of inventing or discovering such a value.
It *uses* TMPDIR if someone *else* sets it.
hth